# MS Access - There is already an object named "xxx" in the database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an earlier version of an MS Access Database, in which I'm updating some of the tables/queries. During the update process, MS Access crashed and I loaded the database again. Some of the tables/queries have gone missing in the new version and if I try to create the queries again with the same name, the error, "There is already an object named 'XXX' in the database" pops up. I tried 'Compact and Repair' with no result. Note that these tables/queries are not temporary as is the case with similar questions on this topic in Stackoverflow. Also, I don't want to drop these tables, rather restore them if possible.

Note that I'm using MS Access 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new database and import the objects you wish to keep from the two other databases.

Comment: This method didn't work. I've created a new database and tried importing tables/queries from the original database. The missing tables/queries are not visible in the list. But in the original database, if I try saving any query with the names of missing files, I get the above error

Comment: But in the new database you can create them. That was the point.

Comment: I have already added copies of my missing queries to the database with a suffix "_v2". So, no issues when it comes to functionality. I'm more inclined to find the reason for these hidden/missing queries and how I can restore them / avoid this issue in the future.